# exert influence vs influence

Tags: word-usage, meaning, word-choice, difference

What are the differences between them?

- *influence*
- *exert influence*

The latter is more emotional and stronger, isn't it?

(The translation of these two words into my language are absolutely the same.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The use of "exert influence" has the overtone of intent.

"The decision of the Prime Minister influenced the stock market."

It may or may not have been the intention of the Prime Minister to influence the stock market, but there is no declaration of such.

"The prime minister exerted his influence over the stock market by embarking on [whatever policy]."

This means that he knew what he was doing, by intentionally doing what he did.

Apologies that the examples are a little clumsy, I am thinking as I type.

Comment: I've got. Thank you!